# What is the shorthand way of raising a variable to the power of - in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the formula for calculating the volume of a sphere, the radius is raised to the power of 3. So, if I assign a variable such as sphere_radius to the radius, how would I raise that variable to the power of 3 (in shorthand form without having to multiply the radius three times) in my python statement to calculate the volume?

Comment: [pow()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_pow.asp)

Comment: @MohamadGhaithAlzin please reference the official Python docs - [`pow()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) - instead of a lousy, error-prone SEO-driven website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, `a**b` will raise a to the power of b.

For example:

```
cubed = radius ** 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will go ahead and check it out in my code.

Comment: @superior_light If this helped you in any way upvote and mark as accepted as that helps a ton and can also help future readers